# Using StringSplitOptions to get word list VB.NET

Tags: vb.net

trying to get emails list from RichTextBox to be in listbox.

so i used (for each, StringSplitOptions, to split the full text)

Richtextbox : "one@gmail.com two@yahoo.com three@hotmail.com that's all"

Code

```
 For Each str As String In RichTextBox1.Text.Split(New String() {"@"}, StringSplitOptions.None)

        ListBox1.Items.Add(str.Substring(str.LastIndexOf(" ") + 1))

 Next
```

result in listbox :

> one
>
> two
>
> three
>
> all

Comment: Why are you splitting on "@" if you want the email address?  Why not split on " "?

Comment: "@" to get all mail address, it cant only be like gmail, cause there many mail services like yahoo,,, etc. so i want it generally for all emails

Comment: So why can't you split on a space?

Comment: when split on a space i get huge list, and richtextbox could be have massive of text that why i only wanna grab only mails from richtextbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if u search on "@Gmail.com"
you can change the loop to integer

for i = 0 to Length - 1
and use substring

### (str.substring(str.indexof(" "), str.indexof(" .com")), or just add +@gmail.com

Well its normal cause u getting splits @, So u need to use Regex

but in that case u find all mail forum, so i recommended, to get valid email list, search on (@ and also .) which contain emails list.

```
Dim reg As Regex = New Regex("(([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]+|([a-zA-Z]{1}|[\w-]{2,}))@" &
               "((([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\." &
               "([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])\.([0-1]?[0-9]{1,2}|25[0-5]|2[0-4][0-9])){1}|" &
                "([a-zA-Z]+[\w-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,4})", RegexOptions.Compiled Or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)

    For Each email As Match In reg.Matches(RichTextBox1.Text)
        ListBox1.Items.Add(email.Value.ToString())
    Next

MessageBox.Show("Done")
```

Hope it work